# trying to validate form using codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

hi i am trying to make a simple validation form but fore some reason its not working i tried to fallow the codeigniter user guide but it dose not work for me fore some reason i am only a beginner.can someone have a look at my code and help me out tnx for you help. all i get is an error message page not found and the form itself dose not validate. when i clik the submit button it goes to this url `HTTP://localhost/Surva/index.php/info/validation`

**controller**

```
<?php

class Info extends CI_Controller{

 public function index(){
 $this->load->view('info_view');


 $data ['name'] =        $this->input->post('name');
 $data ['second_name'] = $this->input->post('second_name');
 $data ['phone'] =       $this->input->post('phone');   
 $data ['email'] =       $this->input->post('email');

 if($this->input->post('submit')){

     $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|alpha|xss_clean');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_name', 'Second Name', 'required|alpha|xss_clean');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

     if ($this->form_validation->run()){

         $this->info_model->add_record($data);

     }
 }
     $this->load->view('survay_view');
 }




 }


?>
```

**view**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 
 <body>

   <?php 
   echo validation_errors();
   echo form_open('info/validation'); ?>
     <ul id="info">  

       <li><label for='name'>Name:</lable><?php echo form_input('name')?></li>


       <li><label for='second_name'>Second Name:</lable> <?php echo form_input('second_name');?> </li>


       <li><label fro='phpne'>Phone:</lable> <?php echo form_input('phone');?></li>


       <li><label for='email'>Email:</lable><?php echo form_input('email');?></li>

       <li><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Start survay!!' );?></li>
     </ul>  

 <?php echo form_close();?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**model**

```
<?php

class Info_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_records()
          {
          $query = $this->db->get('credentials');

          return $query->result();   
          }


    function add_record($data)
          {
          $this->db->insert('credentials', $data);
          return;
       }


}

?>
```

Comment: did you load the form_validation library?

Comment: what is not working for you?? are you getting any error or its not validating fields?

Comment: i am getting an error page not found when i click on the submit button and also it is not validating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo form_open('info/validation');
```

Your form asks to go into the controller called "Info", and a function called "validation".

Your controller does not have that function.

Try changing it to:

```
echo form_open('info');
```

since you are doing your validation in your index function.

Comment: that was the problem i was calling the validation function where i had to call validation_info function tnx for you help

Answer (score 0):

load the form_validation library in your controller, you forgot to load it.

```
public function index(){
 $this->load->view('info_view');
 $this->load->library('form_validation');  // load library.
 ...............

}
```

change

```
 echo form_open('info/validation');
```

to

```
 echo form_open('info/');
```

Comment: the library is auto loaded.

Comment: from where, is it loaded through constructor?

Comment: its loaded in the config/autoload.

Comment: may be your library is not loading , through autoload.

Comment: it works fine i am also loading the form library an i already tried to load the library manual nothing changed.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar if the library isn't loaded it would be a completely different error. Read his comments, his error is something else

Comment: @HeHui thanks for pointing out. But he hasn't mentioned this error before. :)